# Puppet configuration to create file

Tags: puppet

I am trying to create a vagrant box to use for development with Puppet as provisioner. I want to set a specific .bashrc for the vagrant user.

Here are my relevant files.

**dev.pp**:

```
class dev {

    $target = "dev"
    $root_dir = "/home/vagrant/demo"
    $user = "demo"
    $group = "demo"

    class { "demo":
        target => $target,
        root_dir => $root_dir,
        user => $user,
        group => $group;
    }

    class { "demo::app::site": }

}

class { "dev": }
```

**modules/demo/manifests/init.pp:**

```
class demo ($target, $root_dir, $user, $group) {

    group { $group:
        ensure => present;
    }

    user { $user:
        ensure     => present,
        managehome => true,
        shell      => '/bin/bash',
        gid        => $user,
        require    => Group[$group];
    }

    file {
        $root_dir:
            owner   => $user,
            group   => $group,
            ensure  => directory,
            require => User[$user];        
    }

    file { "/home/${user}/.bashrc":
        ensure => present,
        owner   => $user,
        group   => $group,
        mode    => '755',
        content => template("${module_name}/bashrc.erb"),
        require => User[$user];
    }

    if $target == 'dev' {
        file { $source_dir:
            owner   => $user,
            group   => $group,
            ensure  => directory,
            require => [File[$root_dir], User[$user]];
        }
    }
}
```

**modules/demo/manifests/user.pp:**

```
define demo::user ($ensure=present, $groups=[]) {

  $user = $name

  user { $user:
    ensure     => $ensure,
    groups     => $groups,
    home       => "/home/$user",
    managehome => true,
    shell      => '/bin/bash';
  }

}
```

Everything seems to be working fine. I can execute "vagrant ssh" and I get the VM's command line prompt. But the .bashrc file is not the one defined here:

```
content => template("${module_name}/bashrc.erb"),
```

And if I delete it manually it never gets created again from "vagrant provision". It seems that the file resource definition is never being executed. I'm new to Puppet but I thought that everything that is declared in the class should be executed. And the class is being correctly required, because everything else works fine. Are there any ways for me to debug, using 'notify' is not helpful here.

Comment: do you have under "modules/demo/templates/bashrc.erb"  ?

Comment: To debug you can pass `--debug` to `puppet apply` to see more. One question though: You say you want this file for the vagrant user, but you set `$user = "demo"`. Is the issue that the file is not created in /home/demo? Or /home/vagrant?

Comment: @c4f4t0r yes. In fact, if that file is not present, I get an error. I do not get any errors, but the .bashrc I get is not the one in the template. It seems to be a default one.

Comment: @faker you hit the nail on the head. That was the bug. $user should be "vagrant" instead of "demo". If you post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to manage `/home/vagrant/.bashrc` but you set:

```
$user = "demo"
```

which gets used later:

```
file { "/home/${user}/.bashrc":
    ensure => present,
    owner   => $user,
```

so you'll just need to change the user variable to vagrant.